# Replacing several different characters in NSString

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, replace, nsregularexpression

I am making an iPad app for personal use and I m struggling with some character replacement in some strings. For example I got an NSString which contains "\t\t\t   C    D". Now what I want to do is replace every C and every D there is in there with C# and D#. I have managed to do that but unfortunately it doesn't look efficient at all to me.

Here is my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(sender)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *newTab = [[NSString alloc] init];
        NSRegularExpression *regexC = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"C" options:0 error:&error];
        NSRegularExpression *regexD = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"D" options:0 error:&error];

        newTab = [regexC stringByReplacingMatchesInString:self.tab options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, self.tab.length) withTemplate:@"C#"];

        NSString *newTabAfterFirstRegex = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newTab];

        newTabAfterFirstRegex = [regexD stringByReplacingMatchesInString:newTab options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, newTab.length) withTemplate:@"D#"];

        NSLog(@"%@",newTabAfterFirstRegex);
    }
```

}

Plus this is just a small tester code. What I would really like to do is to have an algorithm that checks for instances of all music tabs (C C# D D# E F F# G G# A A# B) in a given string and when the IBAction is triggered I would like each one of them to be replaced by the next one (and B becomes C).

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a regular expression (e.g. '[A-G]#?') to match certain strings. With method `-matchesInString:options:range:` you can loop through all the matches (it will give back a range for each match) and use that range to do the replacements.

Comment: Hi again! I did what you suggested. I ended up with an array containing a couple elements "

<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x743eea0>{4, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x743e510> [A-G]#? 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x743ed00>{6, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x743e510> [A-G]#? 0x0}"

I am not sure though how am I supposed to replace a substring from the ranges. I saw in the documentation that these two elements are of class NSTextCheckingResult and they have a range property but how should I use it?

Comment: I understand that {4,1} and {6,1} are the ranges that of the characters that need to be replaced, but again I can't get how should I get the characters from these ranges and compare them somehow and then make the changes. Thank you very much!

Comment: The NSTextCheckingResult objects in the array resulting from `matchesInString:options:range` have a `range` property.You can then use NSString's `-stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` to replace the characters.

Comment: You can get the string of a range with NSString's `-substringWithRange:`

Comment: Hi again Diederik. Your way worked perfect for extracting and replacing just the tab elements, unfortunately it didn't work for the rest of the spaces. I am trying to maintain the rest of the spaces in the string as well. I m starting to think that I should probably play with the ranges of the elements and maybe append them in the end of my for loop? Any ideas on that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions seem a bit like overkill for this, you could just do two string replacements, so that you don't get all the overhead from regexes, using

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                    withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

and just replace it twice. Also, you don't need to do the NSString allocations, because it creates a reference in the return.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following methods for encryption the other day.  I've tested it for your purpose, and it seems to work.

```
-(NSString *)ReplaceMe:(NSString *)s {
// Putting the source into an array
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    [myArray addObject: [self Mid:s :i :1]];
}
// Creating a string with the revised array
NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString new];
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    [myString appendString:[self Conversion:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
// Final
return myString;
}
```

The method above requires two additional functions.

```
-(NSString *)Mid:(NSString *)str:(NSInteger)s:(NSInteger)l {
if ((s <= str.length-1) && (s + l <= str.length) && (s >= 0) && (l >= 1)) {
    return [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(s, l)];
}
else {
    return @"";
}
}
```

The other is...

```
-(NSString *)Conversion:(NSString *)s {
if ([s isEqualToString:@"C"]) {
    return @"C#";
}
else if ([s isEqualToString:@"D"]) {
    return @"D#";
}
else {
    return s;
}
}
```

You can put other conversion pairs in the function above.  The following is an example as to how to use ReplaceMe.

```
- (IBAction)clickAction:(id)sender {
textField2.text = [self ReplaceMe:textField1.text];
}
```

So it's ReplaceMe is quite easy to use.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your time. I tested and it works indeed for the example above, however if a string contains "C C# D D#" and lets say you make more conditions in (NSString *)Conversion:(NSString *)s, then unfortunately it won't be able to recognise the difference between C and C#. It will treat it as C. Maybe I can try and mix some regex in there. Again thank you very much. It was very helpful!!!